# Forbid a character (double quotes) with regular expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm a totally a noob in regular expressions. For a Ruby on Rails project I need one field to allow all letters but forbid double quotes. Any idea how to formulate that ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the [format validation helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#format):

```
validates :your_field, format => {
  :with => /\A[^"]+\z/,
  :message => "No quotes allowed"
}
```

The regex in words:

`\A` from the start of the string

`[^"]` allow any character except `"`

`+` one or more times

`\z` to the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

Just use a negated character class:

```
[^"]
```

The character class will contain all characters *except* the double quote. If you want to validate a string with that you probably want

```
^[^"]*$
```

to match the string against.

Answer (score 0):

**You could use:**

```
if subject =~ /\b[[:alpha:]]+\b/i
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

**Explanation**

```
"
\\b             # Assert position at a word boundary
[[:alpha:]]    # Match a single character present in the list below
                  # A character in the POSIX character class “alpha”
   +              # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\\b             # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that every character from the start to the end must not be  `"`:

```
^[^"]*$
```

This means:
`^`: Match must start at the beginning of the line or string;
`[^"]`: Match any character (letter, punctuation, ...) except `"`;
`*`:  Match the previous item zero or more times;
`$`: Match must end at the end of the line or string.